# How to run if if else condition based on element visibility in selenium robot framework?

Tags: selenium, conditional-statements, robotframework

I am automating a user registration form flow, where successful registration shows a success message and any validation error throws alert text. For this, I am writing an if-else flow based on the visibility or presence of an element on the page. I will pass the control to a specific keyword with that condition

${SuccessBreadcrumb} is the element which is visible when the registration is successful

**Code Snippet**

```
*** Settings ***
Library  SeleniumLibrary

*** Variables ***
${SuccessBreadcrumb} =  xpath=//a[contains(text(),'Success')]
${SuccessMsgLocator} =  xpath=//p[contains(text(), 'successfully created')]
${AlertMsg} =  xpath=//div[@class='text-danger']

*** Keywords ***
Verify Validation Message
    [Arguments]  ${UserDetails}
    sleep  2s
    run keyword if  ${SuccessBreadcrumb}  is visible  Keyword 1
#   ...  else  Keyword 2


Keyword 1
    [Arguments]  ${UserDetails}
    ${AccountCreatedText} =  get text  ${SuccessMsgLocator}
    should contain  ${AccountCreatedText}  ${UserDetails.ValidateMsg}  ignore_case=true

# Keyword 2
```

**Error Log**

```
Run Keyword If ${SuccessBreadcrumb}, is visible, VerifySuccessText
Documentation:  
Runs the given keyword with the given arguments, if condition is true.

Start / End / Elapsed:  20200213 12:27:52.882 / 20200213 12:27:52.882 / 00:00:00.000
12:27:52.882    FAIL    Evaluating expression 'xpath=//a[contains(text(),'Success')]' failed: SyntaxError: invalid syntax (<string>, line 1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the documentation for [Run Keyword If](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Run%20Keyword%20If) there does not exist an example with an object. However, using a combination of Run Keyword If with [Run Keyword And Return Status](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Run%20Keyword%20And%20Return%20Status) will allow you to create a way to handle pass and fail situations within the same test case or keyword.

```
*** Settings ***
Library    SeleniumLibrary

*** Test Cases ***
Check Element Visible
    Open Browser
    ...    url=https://www.google.com
    ...    browser=chrome

    ${passed}    Run Keyword And Return Status  
                 ...    Element Should Be Visible    xpath://*[@id="hplogo"]
    Run Keyword If     ${passed}       Keyword Passed
    ...    ELSE                        Keyword Failed
    [Teardown]    Close Browser

Check Element Not Visible
    Open Browser
    ...    url=https://www.google.com
    ...    browser=chrome

    ${passed}    Run Keyword And Return Status  
                 ...    Element Should Be Visible    xpath://*[@id="xxxx"]
    Run Keyword If     ${passed}       Keyword Passed
    ...    ELSE                        Keyword Failed
    [Teardown]    Close Browser

*** Keywords ***
Keyword Passed
    Log To Console    Passed

Keyword Failed
    Log To Console    Failed
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was able to achieve what I wanted. I appreciate your help. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
${result}    Is Element Visible    ${locator}
IF    ${result} == True
    Click Element    ${locator}
ELSE
    Click Element If Visible    ${locator}
    Wait Until Element Is Visible    ${locator}
    Click Element    ${locator}
END
```

Comment: The same can be achieved using "Is Element visible" keyword.